Is the prefix "for" in "forgo" used as a preposition?
For the majority of usage, the term "forgo" is utilized as a verb. Morphologically speaking, how does the "for" within "forgo" function? Is it a preposition, distinguishing any sort of location, spatial relationship, or lack thereof? Or does "for" simply compound with "go" to build basis towards its definition? I haven't found much else on other forums and websites, but I am quite intrigued to say the least as for the interpretation of "for" as well as its possible multifaceted use.

My dictionary says forgo is from Old English forgān.  So do not expect any new similar uses of for occurring today.  And I think prefix for- is not a preposition.

You can find the etymology of forgo here - and follow the link to the (originally OE) prefix for-; but you ask about the morphology, which GEdgar explains.

Thanks for providing more about the etymology. The clarification certainly serves well and gives a better idea towards the construction of forgo, though I do still seek more of its morphology. @StuartF

The following information is extracted from The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary (1995). In this source, "for-" is considered to be a prefix from OE that is no longer productive. There is in this etymology a partial interpretation of this prefix;   "forbid" is found under "prohibition", "forgo" under "abstain, neglect, renounce", which is  akin to "rejection".

forgo /fɔːˈɡəʊ, fə/ v. Also forego … OE [f. FOR-1 + GO v.]


for /fɔː, unstressed fə/ pref.1  (no longer productive) [OE (also fær-)= OFris. for-, fir-, OS for-, OHG fir-, far- (Du., G ver-), Goth. fair-, faur-, corresp. to Gk peri-, para-, L per-, por-, Skt pari, parā, f. IE pref. with variation of form and meaning esp. (i) rejection, exclusion, prohibition, (ii) destruction, (iii) exhaustion]. … 3 Forming vbs. from vbs. w. the sense 'abstain, neglect, renounce' as forbear, forgo, forgive, forget, forsake, forswear

The etymology section is found between brackets.









OE
Old English


OFris.
Old Frisian


OS
Old Saxon


OHG
Old High German


Du.
Dutch


G
German


Goth.
Gothic


Gk
Greek


L
Latin


Skt
Sanskrit


IE
Indo-European


corresp.
corresponding


f.
from


pref.
prefix


esp.
especially


vbs.
verbs


w.
with




Merriam-Webster
gives the first sense of the prefix for- as “so as to involve prohibition, exclusion, omission, failure, neglect, or refusal.” Thus we have not only forgo, but such other words as forbid and forsake.
